# How to solve this SyntaxError in django due to manage.py

Tags: django

I've started learning django. Through the django docs, I am using vscode for the project. The matter is that I've started a new project named "mysite" in the project folder named "web-project" by using the following commands as mentioned in the screenshot

[image]

But if you noticed an error in the last of the screenshot. It pops every time I tried to run the server

Comment: Wrong version of Python? Current versions of Django only support Python 3.

Comment: "python manage.py runserver" is the command